# Receiving Error when I read file line by line in ansible

Tags: ansible

The goal is to read the input file for a string that matches the regex expression then to match the expression to my config file.. when there is a match ansible is to replace the existing line in the config file with the matching line in the delta file.

I was able to perform this task but noticed that ansible would read one line and essentially be done. I added the .splitlines() option to my code so that it would read line by line and perform the same action but i received the following error:

```
    - name: Search for multiple reg expressions and replace in config file
      vars:
        # pull data from config file
        input: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ record }}').splitlines() }}"
        delta: "{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*?', multiline=True )}}"
        delta1: "{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', multiline=True)}}"
        record: "/etc/ansible/roles/file_config/files/records/records.config.{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      lineinfile:
        path: /dir/dir/WCRUcachedir/records.config
       # Line to search/Match against
        regexp: "{{item.From}}"
       # Line to replace with
        line: "{{item.To}}"
        state: present
        backup: yes
      with_items:
       - { From: '{{delta}}', To: '{{delta1}}' }
```

This happened to be my end result

```
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', multiline=True )}}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', multiline=True )}}): expected string or buffer"
}
```

these are what i believe my conflicting lines are

**input: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ record }}').splitlines() }}"**

AND

**delta1: "{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', multiline=True)}}"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you do have another problem.

In the `vars` section, when you're setting `delta` and `delta1`, `regex_search` is expecting a string, but your passing a list (which `splitlines()` created).  But you need it to work on one line at a time.

So, rather that `input`, use `item`, which will be set in the loop:

```
vars:
  input: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ record }}').splitlines() }}"
  delta: "{{ item | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*?')}}"
  delta1: "{{ item | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*')}}"
```

Obviously, you don't need the `multiline=True` any more.

Now, the loop will look like this:

```
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/opt/CCURcache/records.config
  regexp: "{{ delta }}"
  line: "{{ delta1 }}"
  state: present
  backup: yes
loop: "{{ input }}"
when: delta != ""
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped solved the issue i was looking for with trying to get ansible to loop over the multiple lines.. greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only have one `item` to loop over.  That item has two elements, `From` and `To`.

`From` is `{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*?', multiline=True )}}`

`To` is `{{ input | regex_search('^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*_.*[a-zA-Z]+.*', multiline=True)}}`

All you did in the `vars` section was define strings, which will get executed later, when the `regex` and `line` are used in the module.

Now, assuming you need to put these together, you need to [zip them](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together):

```
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/opt/CCURcache/records.config
  regexp: "{{item.0}}"
  line: "{{item.1}}"
  state: present
  backup: yes
  loop: "{{ delta|zip(delta1)|list }}"
```

Here's a simple example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list1:
    - key_1
    - key_2
    - key_n
    list2:
    - value_1
    - value_2
    - value_n

  tasks:
  - name: Loop over lists
    debug:
      msg: "key is {{ item.0 }}; value is {{ item.1 }}"
    loop: "{{ list1|zip(list2)|list }}"
```

And the results:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************

TASK [Loop over lists] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['key_1', 'value_1']) => {
    "msg": "key is key_1; value is value_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['key_2', 'value_2']) => {
    "msg": "key is key_2; value is value_2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['key_n', 'value_n']) => {
    "msg": "key is key_n; value is value_n"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Good luck!